# Commit transactional offset across 2 different clusters

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We are using processors with exactly-once delivery (committing consumer offset through producer) and need to understand whether it is possible for this to happen when consuming a message from a topic in kafka-cluster-1 and producing to a topic on kafka-cluster-2 (and vice-versa).

This is a snippet from the transactional processor:

```
messageProducer.beginTransaction(partitionId)
resultPublisher.publish(partitionId, resultTopic, messageRecord.key(), result)
val offsetAndMetadata = messageConsumer.getUncommittedOffsets(listenTopic, messageRecord)
messageProducer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(partitionId, offsetAndMetadata, consumerGroupId)
messageProducer.commitTransaction(partitionId)
```

My understanding is that a the producer will try to commit the offset on a consumer topic in the same cluster.

I did some research but can't really find anything related to multiple clusters.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can "manually" send offsets to your own topic on the same cluster, where the produced message is sent. This way you can use guarantees provided by transactions.

You would need to create your own topic for offsets, similar to Kafka's internal __consumer_offsets, where as key you should use groupId, topic, partition, and as value the most recent offset (already read or to be read). Remember to use log compaction.

AFAIK there is no possibility to have transaction across two different clusters.